# IHostedService for database changes hung forever

Tags: c#, signalr-hub, webapi, ihostedservice

I am trying to implement database change notificaitons using SignalR in a web api.
below is the code for NotificationService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Npgsql;
using webapi.DBCalls;
using webapi.Models;

namespace webapi.Notification
{
public class NotificationService : IHostedService
{
    private IHubContext<HubConfig> _hub;
    private readonly ModelAppSettings _appSettings;
    private DBInterceptor _db_interceptor;

    public NotificationService(IHubContext<HubConfig> hub, IOptions<ModelAppSettings> appSettings)
    {
        _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
        _db_interceptor = new DBInterceptor(_appSettings);
        _hub = hub;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        onDataTableChangeListener();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void onDataTableChangeListener()
    {
            using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(_appSettings.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                connection.Notification += (o, e) => notifyDataChange(e.Payload);
                using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("LISTEN datachange", connection))
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                while (true)
                    connection.Wait();
            }
    }

    public void notifyDataChange(string payload)
    {
        //DO some work here

    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
}
```

And I am registering this service in Startup.cs under **ConfigurationService** AS below
`services.AddHostedService<NotificationService>();`

When I run the program, it never starts and is hung at below line.

```
while (true) 
  connection.Wait();
```

I know I need to rewrite this method, but not sure how to write it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why are you blocking the thread?

Comment: As Mr. White said: Make your work in onDataTableChangeListener asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

You are not implementing the `IHostedService` interface correctly. You are blocking the current thread with `connection.Wait()`. In `StartAsync` you should start a new thread or a Task on the ThreadPool that will process the notifications in the background. In `StopAsync` you would terminate processing and perform cleanup if needed.

This is partially implemented by the `BackgroundService` class where you have to implement only the `ExecuteAsync` method. Using `BackgroundService` class your service should like this:

```cs
public class NotificationSerice : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection("ConnectionString");
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        connection.Notification += (o, e) => notifyDataChange(e.Payload, stoppingToken);
        
        using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("LISTEN datachange", connection))
            await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(stoppingToken);

        while (true)
            await connection.WaitAsync(stoppingToken);
    }

    private void notifyDataChange(string payload, CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        ///
    }
}
```

In the example it is implemented as an asynchronous method. It is also possible to use `Task.Run()` which runs tasks on the ThreadPool. `stoppingToken` will be triggered when the application shuts down.

Comment: Thank you very much for the sample code, I have implemented it ```Task.Run()``` way.